# Automatically change/instrument Android app's source code

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik, instrumentation

I want to automatically transform the source code of an Android application so that all 
the methods in all classes include two more instructions.

Basically, what I want is to instrument the source code of the app, but with some 
restraints (for instance, an class that extends an Activity needs a different approach 
in the onCreate method).

I saw the [ASM 2.0 Framework](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html), but apparently this framework is designed to manipulate 
JVM bytecode, and Android uses Dalvik Virtual Machine, so it wouldn't work...

Does anyone knows a framework or a tool that I can use for this purpose?
Thanks! :)

Comment: How many classes / methods do you have? What are the "two instructions" you want to add?

Comment: The goal is to make this possible to any number of classes / methods.
The two instructions I want to add are two calls of the same method, with different values on the arguments.

Comment: are you working in any particular IDE?  Looks like you may want to do something that creates a copy/instrumented version from whatever live code is .. without impacting the original source.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want :) A second version, copied from the first one, with the modifications.
I'me working on Eclipse.

Comment: If you are working with eclipse, you may want to consider an eclipse plugin that uses a syntactic recognizer to find methods and instrument them.  Sounds easy .. but with so many variants of code (you will have to use static reference, use reflection to see where you are ..???)

Comment: I don't have that many variants.
I just need to insert the two instructions I said int all methods of all classes, and to make my job easier I may need to insert one more instruction in the classes that extend android.Activity, but that's more flexible. Do you know a plugin that I could use?

Comment: Oh.you are not trying to create a general "instrumenter" plugin.  You might try to create a simple yacc or parser to run across the code then ... there should be a Java parser around (but I don't know where).

Comment: Yes, I thought about a parser too, but a parser for Java language is not the best thing to look at xD
I have the language file for the Antlr parser generator, but that's my last shot, I want to explore other solutions first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors of ASM offer a byte code library similar to ASM that [deals with Android's DEX format](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asmdex.html). The 2.0 version of ASM is old by the way. The [current](http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm/) version number is 4 with 5 being in the beta state.

It does however sound to me like you should not apply this instrumentation at run time. You should usually not use run time byte code generation when you can also generate this code at compile time. Instrumentation is a quite heavy tool.

Instead, maybe source code generation is an option for you? Or maybe your problem is solved as simple as by applying the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)? You might also look into the [Java compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) or into tools like [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/) which you could apply in your [build process](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)
The template method pattern would be useful if I knew exactly the classes/methods I am dealing with, but I want to make this generic, for any app.
Stil, I will look at the ASMDEX framework or Spoon to see if it fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [dexlib2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.smali%7Cdexlib2%7C2.0.3%7Cjar) library. It allows reading/modification/writing of dex files. For example, https://gist.github.com/JesusFreke/6945806

Comment: Thank you for the help! But where can I learn more abou this library?